# Gstreamer decode plugin is not working at full performance in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu, gstreamer, decode

when i run via gstreamer command promp when decode it uses 20% gpu per video. But when I decode it with Opencv it uses 10% gpu per video. I am largely distorted when decoding over Opencv. I think this is the reason. What do you think could be?

cmd pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=9001 caps = application/x-rtp ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvh264dec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

c++ opencv pipeline:

```
Mat frame1current;
    string gst_pipe1 = "udpsrc port=9001 caps = application/x-rtp ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvh264dec ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=false";
    VideoCapture cap1(gst_pipe1, CAP_GSTREAMER);
while (true) {
        cap1.read(frame1Current);
        imshow("1", frame1Current);
             }
```

**Images:**

Video: 3840x2160 h264 .mp4 file

[Stream received over opencv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUMzB.jpg)

[Stream received over cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcWYz.jpg)

Comment: is there any flag in OpenCV to allow the use of hardware accelerated features?

Comment: I didn't add anything about it. I will do research on this subject.

Comment: Does anyone have any other ideas. I still couldn't solve the problem.